# Collision detection problem in monogame C#

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

```
    protected virtual void CollisionDetection()
    {
        if (CanGoRight() == false) pos.X -= velocity;
    }

    protected bool IsTouchingLeft(Basic2d asset)
    {
        return pos.X + dims.X / 2 > asset.pos.X &&
               pos.X - dims.X / 2 < asset.pos.X &&
               pos.Y + dims.Y / 2 < asset.pos.Y + dims.Y &&
               pos.Y - dims.Y / 2 > asset.pos.Y;
    }

    protected bool CanGoRight()
    {
        foreach (Basic2d asset in Globals.GameAssets)
            if (IsTouchingLeft(asset) == true) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

That's my code(just starting) for collision detection. All of this code is in Character class which has also methods for moving and updating and displaying character.

I struggle with collision detection. I have all my assets(blocks) in the list of objects which is in the class named **Globals**. Class character is a subclass of a **Basic2d** class(this is class for all bricks assets).

So I check if a character is overlapping with any of bricks from the list. Criteria for checking left side overlapping is in the **IsTouchingLeft** method and it doesn't work. I cannot see what is wrong with this code, but every time I change sth it works differently but not well.

What should I change?

And the object of **Character** class has an origin point in in the center of the texture, but the object of **Basic2d** class has origin point in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Try the method below (just use `hitLeft` for your case):

```
public HitState checkHit(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
   HitState retv;
    retv.hit = false;
    retv.hitTop = false;
    retv.hitBottom = false;
    retv.hitLeft = false;
    retv.hitRight = false;
    retv.hitInside = false;
    retv.hitExact = false;

    Rectangle temp1 = Rectangle.Intersect(r1, r2);
    if (temp1.Width == 0 && temp1.Height == 0)
    {
        return retv;
    }

    retv.hit = true;
    if (temp1.Y == r1.Y) retv.hitTop = true;
    if (temp1.Y+temp1.Height == r1.Y+r1.Height) retv.hitBottom = true;
    if (temp1.X == r1.X) retv.hitLeft = true;
    if (temp1.X+temp1.Width == r1.X+r1.Width) retv.hitRight = true;

    return retv;
}

public struct HitState
{
    public bool hit; // true if hit
    public bool hitTop; // true if hit top
    public bool hitBottom; // true if hit bottom 
    public bool hitLeft; // true if hit left
    public bool hitRight; // true if hit right
    public bool hitInside; // true if one inside other
    public bool hitExact; // only true if both bounding boxes exact size
}
```